# Direct Table Access Security with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

Greetings!

I have recently built out a template for one of my clients that includes a lot of new features, not the least of which is EF/WCF RIA.

Deployment time is greatly reduced when I can connect via EF directly to a table. No more CRUD SPROCs for all 50 tables. I've read that EF, by default, doesn't allow for standard SQL Injections, but I am wondering if anyone can provide me with a comprehensive security overview, or at least enough data where I can sit down with the senior DBA/Security guy here, and convince him that writing all of the CRUD SPROC's aren't necessary.

I've read [MSDN Security Considerations (Entity Framework)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716760.aspx), [Security for WCF RIA Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626373%28v=vs.91%29.aspx), and a slew of other articles, but I thought I'd give SO a try and ask for some real world implementations & hard evidence in terms of security & EF.

Your thoughts are greatly apprecaited

The senior DBA/Security guy here had a lot of questions about how

Comment: One way to convince could be to run the application in dev/test environment and capture the SQLs, either using TraceSQL or SQL Server Profiler. Those SQL statements would help you a lot in addition to whatever documentation you find on MSDN or anywhere else.

Comment: I agree with amit_g. I have found that the challenge is more cultural than technical for the DBA and security people.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the case here. Anytime we've presented a logical argument for change it has been approved. Thanks for the confirmation though Ed! (and let us both hope the weather here in PDX finally turns around!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your client program never access SQL directly, instead they are calling RIA Service and RIA Service is inside your ASP.NET, which is completely under your control.
2. You can intercept your ObjectContext by overriding methods like SaveChanges and you can limit your IQueryable in your RIA Services Template classes.
3. C# or VB.NET code is very easy to read and understand instead of stored procedures.
4. Maintenance of stored procedure is sure a pain.
5. RIA Service provides you method templates where you can intercept logic and manipulate and monitor actions taken against database.
6. The one and the only difference is, your logic of monitoring and manipulation for CRUD executes inside ASP.NET Application Pool in case of WCF RIA Services and in case of Stored Procedure, it executes within your Database server.
7. In both the cases, your client has no direct access.
8. EF already validates your data before storing in DB against the model you have created.
9. Future edition of SQL Server is coming with inbuilt modelling tools which will anyway deprecate stored procedures for CRUD in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with this as well.  I'm not sure if your situation is the same in the sense you can still use EF with proc function exports.  I can't say I did any better but I did educate the DBA person on the WCF RIA security boundaries.  Meaning if someone can get authenticated they'll still be able to call the service methods that call the procs.  So I guess in my opinion there isn't a huge difference to exposing the entities you need vs exposing service methods that call procs.  I was able to get the person to loosen up their restrictions when I showed them how easy it was to do CRUD operations with Linq to entities, which meant less work for them.